# how to find crystal report printing count?

Tags: winforms, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report 2010 with C#, have a WinForm and want to show Page N of M to user in a Labelwhile printing crystal repots.
How can I impelemnt that?

the code I implemented in ReportViewer:

using System;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms;
using CrystalDecisions.Web;

namespace ComboSearch.Reports
{
    public partial class ReportViewer : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

```
        ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("Employee.rpt");
            rpt.Load(path);
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;                
        }
    }
}
```

}
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: retagged it for you.  You should get an answer back quicker now.

Answer (score 0):

Showing "Page N of M", while printing report can be done by inserting that as a field to the report itself, and position it upon your requirement.

To insert it, use special fields option to insert "Page N of M" field.